# client-client communication using nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, client-server

I would like to communicate 2 web pages page1.html and page2.html. I have thought that page1 is related to a app1.js node application and page2.html to a app2.js node application. The idea is to send data from the page1.html to app1.js using websockets and then the app1.js will send the data to the page2.html. My first idea is that app1.js sends data to app2.js and then app2.js to the page2.html. I know how to use web sockets to communicate (client-server)  the page1.html with the app1.js but how to send data from app1.js to app2.js? In the app1.js I have

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(3000); //and 

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('GETDATAFROMPAGE1', function (data){
         .....I Get data to be sent to app2?
    });
}
```

Do I need to create a new io2 for other port? How can I do to send data to the app2.html?
I know how to do a client server communication but I don't know server-server communication and how to mix both 
Summary: page1.html -> app1.js --> app2.js --> page2.html   using websockets
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can implement this in an easy way but you don't know because you said you want to send data from page1 to app1 and from app1 to app2 and from app2 to page2. So Basically if I got you correct, you want to send data from page1 to page2. You can create only one server in app.js and use socket.io to connect both pages to send data to each other.

Let's say you have `page1.html`:

```
socket.emit('GETDATAFROMPAGE1', data);
```

and `page2.html`:

```
socket.on('dataFromPage1', function(data){
    //do something
});
```

and you have `app.js`:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('GETDATAFROMPAGE1', function (data){
     socket.broadcast.emit('dataFromPage1', data)
    });
}
```

The *broadcast* event only emits to other than the sender of the data. Now you can send data from page1.html to server and from server to page2.html

Comment: It seems a better solution, thanks... I am going to try

Comment: If page1.html is different from page2.html how you do to open page1.html and page2.html using only app.js? I thought every web page is related to a js node application?

Comment: You first need to understand how node.js works. You can render as many pages as you want with a single server. Look for routing and rendering. Use [expressjs](http://expressjs.com) which is a module for Node.js. See any tutorials for Node.js express and socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) create HTTP routes which handle posting/getting data back end forth between both servers (I assume that it is trivial and you know how to configure route and get/post date between the servers)

2) you can use sockets on the server level as well. Take a look at node's net documentation http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

your code would look something like this:

```
    //server
        var net = require('net');
        var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
          console.log('server connected');
          c.on('end', function() {
            console.log('server disconnected');
          });
          c.write('hello\r\n');
          c.pipe(c);
        });
        server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
          console.log('server bound');
        });

  //client
        var net = require('net');
        var client = net.connect({port: 8124},
            function() { //'connect' listener
          console.log('client connected');
          client.write('world!\r\n');
        });
        client.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log(data.toString());
          client.end();
        });
        client.on('end', function() {
          console.log('client disconnected');
        });
```

You can also use [json-socket](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/json-socket-sending-json-over-tcp-in-node.js-using-sockets).

Comment: thanks ... To use it in my code: I would need to use the server inside the socket.on? -> socket.on('GETDATAFROMPAGE1', function (data){  ...........var server = net.createServer(......your code...)     });

Comment: Your code is for communicating between browser and servers. So inside your code you need to pipe the data to the app1 <-> app2 socket stream.

Comment: I would like to give you a point but I have not 15 of reputation

Comment: Don't worry.. Some day you will have. Instead of giving me a point - help someone else on SO : )